# WPF событие при наведении мыши

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

нужна помощь с кодом XAML:
у меня есть полигон, который постоянно двигается по определенной траектории:

```
<Canvas >
        <Path Stroke="LightBlue" Data="{StaticResource pathg}" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" />
        <Polygon Name="polygon1" Stroke="Yellow" Fill="Yellow"  Points="-100,150 -80,140 -80,120 -35,150 -80,180 -80,160 ">
            <Polygon.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                   Duration="0:0:15" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathg}" Source="Y" >
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                   Duration="0:0:15" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathg}" Source="X" >
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Polygon.Triggers>
        </Polygon>
    </Canvas>
```

Что нужно добавить и куда, чтобы при наведении курсора на полигон, он останавливался (движение прекращалось), а когда курсор убираешь, продолжал движение

Answer (score 4):

Задайте имя объекту `BeginStoryboard`:

```
<BeginStoryboard Name="Storyboard">
```

Затем добавьте два дополнительных триггера в секцию `Polygon.Triggers`:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard" />
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard" />
</EventTrigger>
```